# How to force mobile browsers to pull out numeric keyboard for input type="text"?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, angularjs

In my angularjs app, i have two input fields with `type="text"`, [pls see the plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/T9nrjP1LePGYwF8C0yBH).

The problem is that the currency formatting is not possible for `input type="number"`.

So it it possible to bring up Numeric keyborad for mobile devices when the focus move to `input type="text"`?

Please help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use "tel" I'm sure this will solve your problem. this will allow you to input alphabates also but it will open numeric keypad

```
<input type="tel">
```

Comment: Nice, this still is the best solution 5 years later. Only solution that works with both Android/iOS on multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Add **pattern** to it.

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*">
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same. But then I understood that there's a need also for currency symbols? Or what is the `currency formatting` @Irshu is referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. Additionally you can add "ng-pattern" to manage validation messages etc.

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*">
```